# Abstract class as attribute in Interface which will be overwritten to child class

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, spring-boot

Given that `Bean` is an abstract class and `Venue` class extends `Bean`. ControllerInterface is an interface and VenueController implements this interface.

## interface

```
public interface ControllerInterface {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List getAll();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Bean getOneById(@PathVariable(value = "id", required = true) String id);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Bean updateOne(@PathVariable("id") String id,Bean beanData);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addOne();
}
```

## normal class

```
public class VenueController implements ControllerInterface{

    @Autowired
    VenueDAO venueDAO;

    @Override
    public List<Venue> getAll() {
        return venueDAO.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Bean getOneById(@PathVariable(value = "id", required = true) String id) {
        return venueDAO.findBy(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String addOne() {
        // TODO : add a new venue and return its id
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Bean updateOne(@PathVariable("id") String id, Bean data) {
        Venue venueData = (Venue) data;
        Venue venue = venueDAO.findBy(id);
        Util.copyNonNullProperties(venueData, venue);
        venueDAO.update(venue);
        return null;
    }


}
```

obviously this code will lead to InstantiationException in `public @ResponseBody Bean updateOne(@PathVariable("id") String id, Bean data)`
because the Bean is an abstract class and no way to initialise it.

So my question is how to make this possible ?
I thought of changing `Bean data` to `Venue data` but it's not working since this changes the method signature and wont be overwritten then.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Just some advice be careful with your annotated methods being inherited, I have found many times that my annotations did not carry through and these errors become very difficult to trace.

You will need to use generics `ControllerInterface<SOME extends Bean>`, and then use `SOME` instead of `Bean`.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the advice, thought i never faced this before (it always inherited the annotations) but i do understand why it might not work.